# <input type="number"> scroll behaviour differ with React

Tags: html, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => (
  <input
    type="number"
    min={0}
    max={99999}
    step={1}
  />
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit rr0qj41omq]

If i focus the input box and enter a number, I'm able to change the number by using the mouse scroll wheel while hovered over the input box.

However, when I create a .html file with the following content, I'm **not** able to change the number via scrolling. Any idea what's the reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <input
      type="number"
      min={0}
      max={99999}
      step={1}
    />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the scrolling behavior depends on whether there is an `onWheel` handler or not. When rendering two inputs on a page there is a difference:

```
<input id="input1" type="number" min="0" max="99999" step="1">
<input id="input2" type="number" min="0" max="99999" step="1" onwheel="">
```

Here `input2` increments/decrements its value on mouse wheel, but `input1` doesn't.

Since React attaches its own event handlers to dom elements, inputs are  enabling this `increment on mouse wheel` feature and behave differently comparing to a plain HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Bracket syntax is not valid HTML. They're used in JSX to insert javascript code inside HTML syntax, but obviously that will not work in pure HTML.

The equivalent HTML would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <input
      type="number"
      min="0"
      max="99999"
      step="1"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/reay785h/)

Note that in both cases (React and HTML), the input needs to have focus for scrolling to work. This ability to scroll might also be a browser-dependent behavior.

Also, note that if you inspect the HTML that's being output by your React example, you'll see the same HTML that I've written above, so this is definitely not a behavior specific to React.

Comment: Still wouldn't change with mouse wheel scroll though. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Avery235 Yes, see working example linked in answer.

Comment: It works on jsfiddle, but try saving the code as a local .html file and opening it with browser.

Comment: @Avery235 It's highly possible that jsfiddle added custom event handlers behind the scenes to handle mousewheel events inside inputs of type "number". My point was that the behavior (or lack thereof) isn't tied specifically to React. Finally, you could easily create a <NumberInput> component that behaves the same way, and use that in your app.

Comment: For reference, they're probably using something like this: https://css-tricks.com/mousewheel-inputs/

Comment: It works if deployed as an actual web app too. What's the difference in environment between an actual web app and a local .html file, if both are opened with same browser, that causes the mouse wheel not to work only for local html files?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <input
      type="number"
      min=0
      max=99999
      step=1
    />
   </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure where you tried the .html but it seem to have the same behaviour on scroll. Check the codepen link.

https://codepen.io/nandukalidindi/pen/WXpgwr

However when I tried to render the .html on my local chrome browser, the scroll was not working and same with the React. Neither of them responded to scroll on local browser. I am not sure how the environments differ.

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute onWheel like this to prevent increasing or decreasing value when mouse scrolling:

```
onWheel={(e) => e.currentTarget.blur()}
```